# há um jeito melhor de verificar quantos inputs foram checkados?

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/3q4h6tnL/

Um exemplo em HTML:

```
<div id="1" style="background-color: red;">
    <input type="radio" name="pergunta1">
    <input type="radio" name="pergunta1">
    <input type="radio" name="pergunta1">
    <input type="radio" name="pergunta2">    
</div>

<div id="2">
    <input type="radio" name="pergunta2">
    <input type="radio" name="pergunta2">
    <input type="radio" name="pergunta2">
    <input type="radio" name="pergunta2">    
</div>

<div id="3" style="background-color: red;">
    <input type="radio" name="pergunta3">
    <input type="radio" name="pergunta3">
    <input type="radio" name="pergunta3">
    <input type="radio" name="pergunta3">    
</div>    

<div id="4">
    <input type="radio" name="pergunta4">
    <input type="radio" name="pergunta4">
    <input type="radio" name="pergunta4">
    <input type="radio" name="pergunta4">    
</div>        

<div id="5" style="background-color: blue;">
    <input type="radio" name="pergunta5_5">
    <input type="radio" name="pergunta5_5">
</div>            

<input type="button" value="verificar" id="btn-verifica">
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btn-verifica").on("click",function(){
        var contador = 0;
        var totalQuestoes = 5;
        for(var i =0;i<=totalQuestoes; i++){
            if(
                $("[name='pergunta"+(i+1)+"']").is(":checked") ||
                $("[name='pergunta"+(i+1)+"_"+(i+1)+"']").is(":checked")
              ){
                contador++;
            }
        }
        alert(contador);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denali,

Pode fazer assim:

```
$("#btn-verifica").on("click",function(){
    alert($("input[name*='pergunta']:checked").length);
});
```

Praticamente todos loops de busca podem ser trocados por seletores jquery, mais sobre isso https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: nossa, bem mais fácil

Comment: que bom que te ajudou @Denali outra dica, praticamente todos seletores jquery podem ser combinados para ir refinando a busca cada vez mais.